# How should MongoDB Realm functions share JS code?

Tags: webpack, realm, node-modules, serverless, mongodb-realm

*Cross-posted at https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/how-should-realm-functions-share-js-code/15052*

So I'm scratching together a mildly complex application where I'd like:

- my Realm functions to share internally written code (snippets in folders in my project structure)
- my Realm functions to make use of NPM modules

I've found this, https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/javascript-folders-for-sharing-code-between-mongodb-realm-functions/13565, which suggests to me that a solution *is coming*, but I'm wondering how everyone here does it.

I'm trying to avoid having to `webpack` or otherwise bundle my internal snippets to address my first point **and also** have to upload a `node_modules` archive to address my second one.

I've tried to inline all my dependencies but haven't found a way that results in output that Realm is happy with (Realm always seems to find *some kind of syntax issue* with the generated JS).

Does someone have a `webpack.config` or other recipe they can share?

FWIW, we're on Typescript@4 and tried targeting various ES levels down to ES5, but nothing seems to fit.